# Updating name with ngModel

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have a class who exports:

```
tempHero: Hero = {
    name: 'Hello',
    attribute: 'Hi',
    description: 'None',
    imagePath: 'Yes',
    spell: this.spell
  }

 onUpdateHeroName(event: any) {
     this.tempHero.name = event.target.value
  }
```

If I use the following method to update the name then it works wonder and I'm able to print out tempHero.name in my template.

If I instead set up input with [(ngModel)]="tempHero.name" does my site crash. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is event.target.value defined?

Comment: What do you mean by "does my site crash"? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: Could you please add your ```HTML``` code

Comment: Im trying to replace the upper input with the new one.

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="onUpdateHeroName($event)">
        {{ tempHero.name }}  this works

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="tempHero.name">
        {{ tempHero.name }}  This does not work

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="onUpdateHeroName($event)">
    {{ tempHero.name }}
```

This doesnt work:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="tempHero.name">
    {{ tempHero.name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right html-angular code is the following:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="onUpdateHeroName($event)">
{{ tempHero.name }}
```

OR update the element when the input box loses focus.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (blur)="onUpdateHeroName($event)">
{{ tempHero.name }}
```